# input text and check button

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

hai guys...

My project is to get a input text from user and user can check their answer by simply click on the button check, if their answer is true a message "good job" will be display. but,my code have an error..can u help to check this code 4 me?  your help i really appreciate...

ans1_box.restrict = "0123456789";
var setUpProblem:Function = function():Void

{
    // Clear the ans1_box and the message_box1 and place focus on message_box1

```
ans1_box.text = "";
message_box1.text = "";
Selection.setFocus("ans1_box");
```

}

//When the "CHECK" button is pressed, check the user's answer.

check_buton.onRelease = function():Void 
{

```
if (eval (ans1_box.text) == "22")
{
    message_box1.text = "Good job!!";
    }
else 
{
    message_box1.text = "Try again."; 
    //Selection.setFocus("ans1_box");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `eval()`

```
if (ans1_box.text == "22"){
        message_box1.text = "Good job!!";
}else {
        message_box1.text = "Try again.";
}
```

Comment: thank 4 helping me... i already get rid the eval() b4....but it still not working..for message box i set it as dynamic text.....